# How can it be that wizards Apparate into Hogwarts in the trailer to Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes Of Grindelwald?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

Hasn't J. K. Rowling read the book "Hogwarts, A History"? According to Hermione and J. K. Rowling herself, apparation has been banned on the Hogwarts grounds since the founding times:

> Some rode broomsticks (a difficult feat when carrying trunks and
>   pets); others commandeered enchanted carts and, later, carriages; some
>   attempted to Apparate (often with disastrous effects, as **the castle
>   and grounds have always been protected with Anti-Apparition Charms**),
>   others rode a variety of magical creatures.
>
> **Source**: [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-hogwarts-express); The Hogwarts Express

In the [new trailer, Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sEaYB4rLFQ), we see wizards Apparate at Hogwarts grounds. How can that be?

Comment: Maybe because it's a sequel to *Fantastic Beasts and Where To Find Them* which was written in 2016 - the same year as *Cursed Child*? Perhaps it too was poisoned by the anti-canon CC?